# Drools example from documentation not working

Tags: java, spring, drools

I am trying to persist my stateful session and trying to use the example from the JBoss documentation:

```
// create the entity manager factory and register it in the environment
EntityManagerFactory emf =
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "org.jbpm.persistence.jpa" );
Environment env = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newEnvironment();
env.set( EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY, emf );

// create a new KIE session that uses JPA to store the runtime state
StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession( kbase, null, env );
int sessionId = ksession.getId();
```

The class KnowledgeBaseFactory does not have a newEnvironment() method. I have searched and tried different versions and imports to no avail. I currently have 7.20.0.Final but I have tried several others.

The code snipped I posted above is from: `https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.20.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_manually_configuring_the_jbpm_engine_to_use_persistence.`
I am not sure what I am missing or what the correct import is.

**UPDATE:**

So after some more research it looks like they keep putting this in their documentation though they have deprecated and the method I couldn't find doesn't exist and you have to go back to a 6.x.x release to find it. Why it's still in their documentation as an example when it doesn't exist is beyond me and wasted a lot of my time.

Comment: Have you considered providing a Pull Request to fix this issue? It sounds like a nice contribution that could save some time to other developers.

Comment: Yep, I have also observed outdated/ incorrect documentations for both JBPM and drools on community page.